# cmake cross compile boost link error

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake, cross-compiling

For my program I want to use some boost libraries but when I make the program I get the error:

```
/home/ubunturik/rpinew/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libboost_regex.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/home/ubunturik/rpinew/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicuuc.so.52: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit st
```

I followed this tutorial http://amgaera.github.io/blog/2014/04/10/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi-on-64-bit-linux/. To get boost I used apt install libboost-all-dev on the raspberry pi and used those files.

Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/rpinew/toolchain/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER $ENV{HOME}/rpinew/toolchain/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# Where is the target environment
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/rpinew/rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")

# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

#for boost
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/ubunturik/rpinew/rootfs/usr/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR /home/ubunturik/rpinew/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex date_time system chrono filesystem program_options thread REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

#Bring the headers, such as Student.h into the project
include_directories(include)

include_directories($ENV{HOME}/rpinew/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf)

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_executable(MonitorApp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MonitorApp ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are heading for cross-compilation, so you installed specific toolchain (compiler, libs etc). Then you tried using usual boost libraries, which were built using ordinary compiler and which depends on ordinary libs. Fail isn't that surprising, is it?

I don't know if there is a simple way, but compiling boost from source code using your compiler and libraries intended for Raspberry Pi should do the trick.